# Is it possible to import a custom model into WDS via API?

Tags: machine-learning, ibm-cloud, watson, watson-discovery

I want to deploy a custom model from WKS (Watson Knowledge Studio) to my WDS (Watson Discovery Service) being hosted on Bluemix but I can't do so through WKS UI (by pressing "Deploy" button as suggested by https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/wks/publish-ml.html#wks_madiscovery) because my WKS was created via Blumix Dedicated/Local environment via syndication, hence not accessible publicly. Therefore, to workaround, I'm wondering if I can export my model as zip (ref: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27048147&aid=1) and import it into my WDS via API or other means. Any suggestion or advise? Do you think it is possible? Any thought is welcome!!!

Comment: A correction: because my **WDS** was created via Blumix Dedicated

Comment: Idea) Or can custom models be shared/transferred/copied among multiple WDS instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deploy WKS model onto Discovery via only WKS UI. The ZIP file exported from WKS is available only for importing WEX, not Discovery/NLU.